# Handling remote events with Java futures

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

I'm programming RPC style communication with microcontrollers in Java. The issue I'm facing is to block client code execution until I receive result from the microcontroller, which comes asynchronously.

Namely, I send commands out and receive results in two different threads (same class, though). The approach I've taken is to use CompletableFuture, but that does not work as I expect it to.

My RPC invoke method sends command out and instantiates CompletableFuture as below:

```
protected synchronized CompletableFuture<String> sendCommand(String command) {
    ... send command ...

    this.handler = new CompletableFuture<String>();

    return this.handler;
}
```

In the calling code that looks like that:

```
CompletableFuture<String> result = procedure.sendCommand("readSensor(0x1508)");
String result = result.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // line X
```

Next, there is listener method which receives data from microcontroller:

```
protected synchronized void onReceiveResult(String data) {
    this.handler.complete(data); // line Y
}
```

I expect that client code execution will block at line X and it indeed does that. But for some reason line Y does not unblock it resulting in the timeout exception.

*To answer comments from below...*

Calling code (sorry, names do not match exactly what I have provided above, but that's the only difference, I think):

```
CompletableFuture<String> result = this.device.sendCommand(cmd);
log.debug("Waiting for callback, result=" + result);
String sid = result.get(timeout, unit);
```

Produces output:

```
2016-10-14 21:58:30 DEBUG RemoteProcedure:36 - Waiting for callback, result=com.***.rpc.RemoteDevice$ActiveProcedure@44c519a2[Not completed]
```

Completion code:

```
log.debug("Dispatching msg [" + msg + "] to a procedure: " + this.commandForResult);
log.debug("result=" + this.result);
log.debug("Cancelled = " + this.result.isCancelled());
log.debug("Done = " + this.result.isDone());
log.debug("CompletedExceptionally = " + this.result.isCompletedExceptionally());

boolean b = this.result.complete(msg);
this.result = null;

log.debug("b=" + b);
```

Produces output:

```
2016-10-14 21:58:35 DEBUG RemoteDevice:141 - Dispatching msg [123] to a procedure: getId;
2016-10-14 21:58:35 DEBUG RemoteDevice:142 - result=com.***.rpc.RemoteDevice$ActiveProcedure@44c519a2[Not completed]
2016-10-14 21:58:35 DEBUG RemoteDevice:143 - Cancelled = false
2016-10-14 21:58:35 DEBUG RemoteDevice:144 - Done = false
2016-10-14 21:58:35 DEBUG RemoteDevice:145 - CompletedExceptionally = false
2016-10-14 21:58:35 DEBUG RemoteDevice:150 - b=true
```

ActiveProcedure is actual CompletableFuture:

```
public static class ActiveProcedure extends CompletableFuture<String> {
    @Getter String command;
    public ActiveProcedure(String command) {
        this.command = command;
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically it should work this way. Are you sure the onReceiveResult was called by the listener thread? And are you sure it calls complete on the very same future which you are waiting for? If another call to sendCommand (issued in a third thread) interferes the future member would have changed. Or the callback is too fast and occurs on an old future member before the new one is created. Maybe re-order: First create the future, then send.

Comment: your methods are synchronized which means that it is some kind of concurrent code. And at the same time you're setting a class field (`this.handler`), return it as a result and update it in `onReceiveResult` method. That is some kind of contradiction as the next thread will reassign `handler` and the old one will never be updated

Comment: RPC means separate JVMs. Are you using separate JVMs and if so then CompletableFuturecannot span those JVMs. Please clarify.

Comment: @Dmitry, those methods are defined as synchronized specifically to avoid unwanted reset of handler variable. That's get updated with every call. Reason: I do not know in response to which call I get input from microcontroller. Therefore I direct everything to latest procedure handler, which is then deciding whether it belong to it.

Comment: @edharned, microcontroller has no java in it. java is only on computer side.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Things got clear:

There was integration issue with underlying library, which I use to communicate with microcontroller. I expected that I receive data from device in a separate thread, but that was happening in same thread. Therefore CompletableFuture.get did not unblock.

I do not understand exactly the mechanism leading to such behaviour, but placing

```
handler.complete(msg);
```

into a separate thread solved the issue.